# Hibernate Conversion Java Date to MySQL YEAR

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I got a problem with storing columns with **MySQL** attribute **YEAR** using Java **Hibernate.**

MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE DateTest (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  year YEAR(4),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

..

Java Access Class

```
public class DateTest implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Integer id;
     private Date year;

    public DateTest() {
    }

    public DateTest(Date year) {
        this.year = year;
    }


    public Integer getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getYear(){
        return this.year;
    }

    public void setYear(Date year){
        this.year = year;
    }

}
```

Java Code to save record

```
DateTestDao tcd = new DateTestDao();
Date dd = new Date();

DateTest dt = new DateTest();
tc.setYear(dd);
tcd.saveRecord(dt);
```

When I want to use Hibernates **session.save** the following error occurs:

ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Data truncated for column 'year' at row 1

Prinicpally, I know why it occurs because the date element is larger than the allowed year attribute, but I dont know how to solve it.

Best Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you trying to write the whole date-object into the year-field? You should use `getYear` to read the year from the date before writing it into `this.year` (and don't forget to add 1900, as you probably need the whole year, not just year-1900).

```
public void setYear(Date year){
    this.year = year.getYear() + 1900;
}
```

Note: you might considering using the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, as most `Date` methods seem to be deprecated.